# Android - Ways to send data to a nearby device without installing an app on the nearby devices

Tags: android, bluetooth, google-nearby

I'm trying to send data (like a notification or something) to a nearby device without an internet connection. The restriction is that the device I'm trying to send data to does not have my app installed.

I've considered using Bluetooth, but the problem is that in order to send data, the external device needs to be running a server socket, which means it would need to be running an app as well.

Any suggestions on how to do such a communication would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Well, if your app is not on the other device, what exactly is supposed to be receiving this "data" that you are sending?

Comment: That's what I would like to know. I'd like the other device to be able to receive data by running something that is standard to android devices (i.e. is available to most factory new devices). I understand that this may not be possible.

Comment: Unless you make this question a *lot* more concrete, you are unlikely to get much in the way of useful help. For example: What is the "data"? What do you expect the receiving device to do with the "data"? Why do you think users would want some other device sending them this "data"? And so on. Android devices do not generally respond to arbitrary data input on arbitrary communications channels, for obvious security reasons.

Comment: I want to send a message to another device. This would notify the other device and ask for confirmation to receive the message. Once accepted, the message would be sent and would be viewable on the other device. This is pretty much my goal.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to send a message to another device. This would notify the other device and ask for confirmation to receive the message. Once accepted, the message would be sent and would be viewable on the other device.

There is nothing in Android that behaves as you describe. The closest thing is SMS, and SMS clients do not usually ask for confirmation.